# Trouble with display:block css affecting surrounding divs

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am having trouble with a display.block CSS that I am applying to a span within a div and it is affecting multiple divs and shifting everything around it to the left of the entire container. In my code, the goal is to have the address displayed as a block, but the phone number and the number still taking up the whole horizontal width of the container. I'm watching a video of how to do this and the person doesn't seem to be facing this issue at all and I'm not sure where I made a misstep. I've attached a screenshot of the page when I run it that shows how the address if shifted as a block but it is also affecting everything next to it even though they have different classes, etc.

[Here is a picture of the Page showing what is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjDsj.png)

```js
function initMap() {
    var seattle = {
        lat: 47.608013,
        lng: -122.335167
    };
    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: seattle,
        zoom: 11,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    });
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.title {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    top: 70px;
    left: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 2px solid #333;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.search-container {
    border-radius: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 155px;
    left: 25px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #454E53;
    display: flex;
}

.search-container .search {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.search-container input {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 25px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    color: white;
}

.search-container input:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.search i {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
}

.stores-list-container {
    width: 360px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    background: white;
    left: 25px;
    top: 228px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    bottom: 20px;
    display: flex;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}


.store-address {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #514C4D;
    margin-top: 30px;

}


.store-address span {
    display: block;
}

.store-phone-number {
    color: #B5ADAD;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>John's Google Map Project</title>
        <script src="js/store-data.js"></script>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c939d0e917.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="title">Store Locator</div>

        <div class="search-container">
            <div class="search">
                <input id="zip-code-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter Zip Code"/>
                <i class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="stores-list-container">
            <div class="stores-list">
                <div class="store-container">
                    <div class="store-address">
                        <span>9100 SE 42nd St</span>
                        <span> Mercer Island, WA 98040</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="store-phone-number">555-555-5555</div>
                    <div class="store-number-container">
                        <div class="store-number">
                         1
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=000000000000000000&callback=initMap"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am not seeing any issue in your code, div is by default `block` so the reason it is moving a bit down cause of `margin-top`. Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/46ycq0w3/102/

Comment: @Manjuboyz The issue is that when I place the display block on the span tag it's actually blocking all the surrounding divs all the way up to the <div class="store-list-container> and I have no idea how. I'm obviously new so idk if I'm explaining it right, but for some reason applying it to that span isn't just affecting the span it's affecting the class of several divs up.

Answer (score 0):

That problem not related to `display: block`, the problem is related to `bottom` property.

Remove `bottom` property from the `stores-list-container` class and your problem will be solved.

```js
function initMap() {
    var seattle = {
        lat: 47.608013,
        lng: -122.335167
    };
    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: seattle,
        zoom: 11,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    });
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.title {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    top: 70px;
    left: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 2px solid #333;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.search-container {
    border-radius: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 155px;
    left: 25px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #454E53;
    display: flex;
}

.search-container .search {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.search-container input {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 25px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    color: white;
}

.search-container input:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.search i {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
}

.stores-list-container {
    width: 360px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    background: white;
    left: 25px;
    top: 228px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    /* bottom: 20px; */
    display: flex;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}


.store-address {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #514C4D;
    margin-top: 30px;

}


.store-address span {
    display: block;
}

.store-phone-number {
    color: #B5ADAD;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>John's Google Map Project</title>
        <script src="js/store-data.js"></script>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c939d0e917.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="title">Store Locator</div>

        <div class="search-container">
            <div class="search">
                <input id="zip-code-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter Zip Code"/>
                <i class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="stores-list-container">
            <div class="stores-list">
                <div class="store-container">
                    <div class="store-address">
                        <span>9100 SE 42nd St</span>
                        <span> Mercer Island, WA 98040</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="store-phone-number">555-555-5555</div>
                    <div class="store-number-container">
                        <div class="store-number">
                         1
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=000000000000000000&callback=initMap"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```